# Why does standard output interprets as error when revived from sub process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, console-application, redirectstandardoutput

I have the following method starting a process and hooking the standard output to the console application I'm Creating.
the `_Log.Info(..)` and `_Log.Error(..)` are using log4.net to output to console and a rolling file..

```
private void RunExternalTool(string toolPath, string workingDirectory, params string[] arguments)
        {
            var toolarguments = arguments != null ? string.Join(" ", arguments) : "";
            _Log.InfoFormat("Starting tool [{0}] with arguments [{1}]...", Path.GetFileName(toolPath), toolarguments);
            var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(toolPath, toolarguments);
            processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => _Log.Info(e.Data);
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => _Log.Error(e.Data);
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit();

            _Log.InfoFormat("External tool [{0}] is done with exit code: {1}", Path.GetFileName(toolPath), process.ExitCode);
            process.Close();
        }
```

now when running a .cmd batch file that uses something like

```
call c:\myprogram.exe
```

all the output received from myprogram.exe is channeled into the `ErrorDataReceived` event.

now i do want it to be logged but i want to log info from sub process and errors.. am i missing something ?  or is it just a bug in .NET framework ?

Comment: Your standard output/error is a pipe just like in windows which is a stream.  the Net library doesn't always behave the way most people expect with streams.  A stream when it reaches the end of data just stops and waits for more data.  The stream doesn't automatically flush when reaching the end unless you set the parameter.  So you have to remember to flush the data before closing the stream.  You are probably getting data from your application/process but the data is just getting lost in the stream.

Comment: I would rule out a bug in the .NET framework. In general the API works fine. Could it be, that the process you start, `myprogram.exe` simply outputs to STDERR (or `Console.Error` in .NET-speak)? What happens when you run that program from the console (CMD) like `myprogram.exe 2>NUL` do you see any output?

Comment: @Christian.K yes i see an output that does not represent an error .. its the c++ linker and its verbose output is wat comming out through the StandardError stream